# Downloading Ruby gems on Windows 7 for x86_64-linux platform

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install the Ruby gem file :
bson_ext - version 1.5.1

on windows 7 command prompt, for x86_64-linux platform.

Hence, the following command:
C:\ruby-1.9.3-p374-i386-mingw32\bin>gem install bson_ext --version 1.5.1 --platform x86_64-linux

But I get the error:

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing bson_ext:

```
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/ruby-1.9.3-p374-i386-mingw32/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
```

checking for asprintf()... *** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:

```
    --with-opt-dir

    --without-opt-dir

    --with-opt-include

    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include

    --with-opt-lib

    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib

    --with-make-prog

    --without-make-prog

    --srcdir=.

    --curdir

    --ruby=C:/ruby-1.9.3-p374-i386-mingw32/bin/ruby
```

C:/ruby-1.9.3-p374-i386-mingw32/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The comp
iler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)

You have to install development tools first.

But I can download other gem files like rails, pony, chronic etc

And the output of ruby -v is :

ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15) [i386-mingw32]

So I think there is not a problem with Dev Kit.

Comment: Are you running an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Hello, question, are you trying to force installation of a linux gem on Windows? Sorry, but `x86_64-linux` and Windows don't mix. There is no pre-compiled binary of bson_ext gem for that platform, neither for Windows. If mkmf (extconf) is failing, then the problem is most likely associated with incorrect DevKit installation or environment. Have you checked this page: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: yes i am running an elevated prompt

Comment: @Luis - I am not facing issue while downloading other x86_64-linux gems like rack, rake, rails,kaminari etc. And also, it is not only with bson_ext that I am facing the problem, the same happens for json, passenger,home_run too. I am unable to understand why I am able to download some gems and some i am not. The link helped,  but not much :-)

Comment: Hello, there is no such thing as x86_64-linux rack: http://rubygems.org/gems/rack/versions. You're simply installing those in your system (windows). You can't install passenger on Windows. There could be network issues for the download problems, but for compilation, you need to properly setup RubyInstaller and DevKit.